# Authentication to host 'www.xyz.com' for user 'username' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Reading from the stream has failed

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc-4

Hello I am using a MySQL db for a MVC4 application. For testing purpose I have set up my db at  http://www.db4free.net/. I have set up the application locally (with remote db at db4free.net) and its running fine(though its is very slow, but still its running). But when I deployed the application in arvixe webserver I am getting the following error.

```
<add name="MySqlMembershipProvider" type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLMembershipProvider,                      MySql.Web,                      Version=6.8.3.0,                      PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" autogenerateschema="true" connectionStringName="SimpleMembershipTestDbContext" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Hashed" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression="" applicationName="/" />
```

Comment: I to am having this exact same problem out of the blue it surfaced today. The application ran fine whether hosted on the server or running locally in debug. The database gives the same exact error to me but only when I try to access mysql data from the hosted application. If I go run it locally in visual studio but with the remote data it doesn't do it.   Any luck with this one???

Comment: Any luck with this one?

Comment: Yes that was my mistake. Changed the password at one connection string. while the other had wrong password